# Accessing a datalayer from a script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension that validates a page according to rules, for example I am checking that values in a datalayer correspond to the values I would expect in various elements.  My testing code works perfectly when pasted into the console.  My aim is to transfer this to an extension.

From a popup I call a function that is in my content script, the content script is like this

```
function testcode (avalue){
    alert(avalue)
    //This works
    data_element_type_count = $('a[data-element-type]').length + 1;
    alert(data_element_type_count)

    //This doesn't
    productListing_count = hcDatalayer.productListing.length + 1;
    alert(productListing_count)
}


testcode ('hello')
```

I get this: Uncaught ReferenceError: hcDatalayer is not defined

When the page loads, and if I run it from a popup the same bits fail

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: ReferenceError: hcDatalayer is not defined
    at testcode (chrome-extension://lbcndjkkmngpdcgojifgolgchhaciipb/contentscript.js:49:28)
    at chrome-extension://lbcndjkkmngpdcgojifgolgchhaciipb/contentscript.js:8:4
```

If paste the following in the console it works

```
productListing_count = hcDatalayer.productListing.length + 1;
alert(productListing_count)
```

I can imagine it not working on page load as perhaps the values haven't been pushed yet, but from the popup I am unsure why it doesn't work, it can obviously access the page as this bit works

```
data_element_type_count = $('a[data-element-type]').length + 1;
alert(data_element_type_count)
```

And from the console it works.  What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Calling content script function from popup page, you should use message passing API here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging